# Is there a way I can activate my .active for a div element using a separate div or list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

opened navigation
[image]
closed navigation
[image]
 
I'm using the .active to create the transition from the hamburger menu to the x.
the problem i'm having is that when I click on an item within the navigation it doesn't transition back to the hamburger menu.

How can I activate the .active ? I got the navigation to slide back up when a link is clicked, but the x doesn't go back to its original state.

```
<div class="fullnavBtn" id="toggle"> <span class="top"></span> <span class="middle"></span> <span class="bottom"></span> </div>


.fullnavBtn.active .top {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
    background: #00a0ca;
}

.fullnavBtn.active .middle {
    opacity: 0;
    background: #00a0ca;
}

.fullnavBtn.active .bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
    background: #00a0ca;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#fullnav').toggleClass('open');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#toggletwo').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#fullnav').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included the div#fullnav and the open class. Looking at the code, I recon the #fullnav is the navigation part which is outside the div#toggle. So you need to include a click event on the div#fullnav which will toggle these classes again.

```
$('#fullnav').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('#toggle').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correction ! It worked perfectly ! It's not the #fullnav that needed to be clicked but the links within it to toggle everything and activate the hamburger menu. Thanks !